# Delay image display on hover

Tags: html, css

I want an image to be displayed after hovering over a specific element for one second.

I've looked through old posts on SO but haven't found anything regarding displaying an image- only modifying it.

Right now, here's an example of what I have in CSS:

```
a.type1,
a.type2{
    position: relative;
}

a.type1:hover:after,
a.type2:hover:after{
    content: url(imageurlgoeshere);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;

}
```

I've tried adding transition-delay and others however I'm fairly sure that it doesn't work because content is not an animatable property.

While I think using opacity might work, I don't want the image to be rendered until the user hovers.

I've tried using background-image, but I ran into some trouble.
In some cases, the cursor flickers due to what I can assume to be the element disappearing and losing it's hover state.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/34391120/4229270

Comment: @Karthikeyansundaramoorthi Yeah- i'd like to keep it in CSS only.

Comment: @Sinto That snippet suffers the same issue- it doesn't delay the execution of the hover effect. It does it instantly. I could probably do this in JS rather quickly but I'd like to keep it 100% CSS for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `transition` to hide and show images using the `opacity` property, with `transition-delay` used to delay the change of opacity.

In this example, [`pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) is placed on the pseudo elements so that they will only show when the links themselves are hovered.

Here is a [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ocf67fmb/):

```css
a.type1,
a.type2 {
  position: relative;
}
a.type1:after,
a.type2:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/rG8mD.png);
  transition: opacity 2s;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
a.type1:hover:after,
a.type2:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 1s;
}
```

```html
<a class="type1">Type One</a>
<br />
<a class="type2">Type Two</a>
```

Comment: Yeah- the fade in effect is nice- I'll probably use that, but I still can't figure out how to apply the effects after 1 second of hovering.

Comment: @MW - use `transition-delay` like [this example here](https://jsfiddle.net/v3j2kk85/). In this example it is 2 seconds. If you put in on the `:hover` then it will only apply when the element is hovered and then fade out with no delay when no longer hovered. The transition delay will work because you are now controlling the opacity.

Comment: @misterManSam Thanks :)

Comment: @SunilGehlot - I fleshed out the answer a bit so that it has a full explanation.